# Java - Cipher custom provider

Tags: java, android, encryption

I have an android app with decrypt function like this:

```
private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] keybytes, byte[] data)
{
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keybytes, "AES");
    Cipher localCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/ZeroBytePadding");
    localCipher.init(2, key);
    return localCipher.doFinal(data);
}
```

This works fine in the app, but I need an java application for my pc to be able to perform the decrypting too, but the following code gives me error:

"Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting AES/ECB/ZeroBytePadding"

I read that JRE doesn't have the correct provider to support this algorithm (I think it is Bouncy Castle).

So how can I add this provider or alternately a workaround to perform the same functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the [Bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) provider to your project and make certain you have registered the provider with the [Security](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Security.html) class prior to calling Cipher.getInstance(). You can do this by something like:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed!